# react native bottom sheet integrating into home screen

Tags: android, html, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am following the below tutorial and trying to implement the react native bottom sheet in my Home Screen.
I used all his codes but still I am not able to open the bottom sheet when I click the filters button
Providing the video tutorial, GitHub link and my code below below
Its throwing an error at this line —>     bs = React.createRef();
Can you let me know how to fix it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjJzaiGkaQA

https://github.com/itzpradip/Food-Finder-React-Native-App/blob/master/screens/EditProfileScreen.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
//import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import {Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import MapView from 'react-native-map-clustering';
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';
import {GooglePlacesAutocomplete} from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

//import {Button} from 'react-native';
import {
  Image,
  LogBox,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import {Button, Menu, Provider} from 'react-native-paper';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
//import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';
//import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import BottomSheet from 'reanimated-bottom-sheet';

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const data = ['dropdown1', 'drop down 2', 'a drop down'];

const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen2" component={HomeScreen2} />
      {/* <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen7" component={HomeScreen7}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen8" component={HomeScreen8}/> */}
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={Main}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="AuthStack">{() => <AuthStack />}</Stack.Screen>

        {/* <AuthStack /> */}
        {/* <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingScreen" component={OnboardingScreen} /> */}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const Main = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      }}>
      <View style={{}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#20315f'}}>
          GAMEON
        </Text>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AuthStack')}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#AD40AF',
          padding: 20,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          color: '#fff',
          width: '90%',
          marginBottom: 50,
        }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: '#fff',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          }}>
          Let's Begin
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      }}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#20315f'}}>
        Home
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const HomeScreen2 = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        // provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        // remove if not using Google Maps
        style={styles.map}
        region={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.015,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
        }}></MapView>

      {/* <View style={styles.searchBox}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Search here"
          placeholderTextColor="#000"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          style={{flex: 1, padding: 0}}
        />
      </View> */}

      <View style={styles.searchBox}>
        <Autocomplete

        //onChangeText={}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  bs = React.createRef();
  fall = new Animated.Value(1);

  // renderInner = () => (
  //     <View style={styles.panel}>
  //       <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
  //         <Text style={styles.panelTitle}>Upload Photo</Text>
  //         <Text style={styles.panelSubtitle}>Choose Your Profile Picture</Text>
  //       </View>
  //       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.panelButton} onPress={takePhotoFromCamera}>
  //         <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Take Photo</Text>
  //       </TouchableOpacity>
  //       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.panelButton} onPress={choosePhotoFromLibrary}>
  //         <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Choose From Library</Text>
  //       </TouchableOpacity>
  //       <TouchableOpacity
  //         style={styles.panelButton}
  //         onPress={() => this.bs.current.snapTo(1)}>
  //         <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Cancel</Text>
  //       </TouchableOpacity>
  //     </View>
  //   );

  //   renderHeader = () => (
  //     <View style={styles.header}>
  //       <View style={styles.panelHeader}>
  //         <View style={styles.panelHandle} />
  //       </View>
  //     </View>
  //   );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 0.4,
          zIndex: 100,
          elevation: 1000,
        }}>
        <ScrollView
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          horizontal={true}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              margin: 10,
              flex: 1,
              zIndex: 100,
            }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.bs.current.snapTo(0)}>
              <Text>filters</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            {/* <BottomSheet
                                ref={this.bs}
                                snapPoints={[330, 0]}
                                renderContent={this.renderInner}
                                renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
                                initialSnap={1}
                                callbackNode={this.fall}
                                enabledGestureInteraction={true}
                            /> */}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const INITIAL_REGION = {
  latitude: 52.5,
  longitude: 19.2,
  latitudeDelta: 8.5,
  longitudeDelta: 8.5,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    //  ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,

    //  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    //  alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },

  searchBox: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 150,
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 8 : 4,
    // flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    width: '60%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderRadius: 5,
    //padding: 5,
    //shadowColor: '#ccc',
    height: '4%',
    // marginLeft: 249,
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 3},
    //shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    // shadowRadius: 5,
    //elevation: 10,
  },

  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },

  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here.
[image]

You can't use "this" with functional components. If you use `bs.current.snapTo(0)`, it will open the sheet.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. I updated my code with your changes, but still I am getting bs is not defined error. Can you update the bottom sheet functionality alone in my code snippet?

Comment: Firstly Clear all "this" usage in bottomsheet code. Then use useref for using react ref. İ mean that const bs=useRef()